# How to update an Elastic Beanstalk app from the AWS command line tool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

Ah, I love/hate AWS.

So, how do I actually update an application in Elastic Beanstalk from the command line?

**side note:** I tried the eb cli, the install broke my aws cli install, so that's not gonna work.

The AWS command line tool, provides an `update-environment` command and an `update-application` command, and ways to update "versions" none of which seem to change the actual code.

How do I use the command line tools: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/update-environment.html to update the actual source code of my application?

Comment: The easiest way is going to be via `eb deploy myenv`, so I'd recommend you focus on fixing your issues with the eb/aws CLI tool first before trying to roll your own deployment mechanism. It's entirely feasible to have both eb and aws CLI installed simultaneously. What do you mean that the eb install "broke my aws cli install"?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Thanks @Brian.

Answer (score 2):

By using (eb deploy environmentname) command you can deploy updated code to existing environment and if it give error like:

```
ERROR: TypeError - must be str, not NoneType
```

then you need to update region in `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` file.