# How to get the AWS EB CLI tool working?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to install the AWS EB CLI tool. Here's the error code I'm getting when I try to run eb:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/eb", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('awsebcli==3.8.4', 'console_scripts', 'eb')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 565, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2631, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2291, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2297, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ebcli/core/ebcore.py", line 43, in <module>
    from . import ebglobals, base, io, hooks
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ebcli/core/base.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ebcli import __version__
ImportError: cannot import name __version__
```

I'm on Python 2.7.6, pip 9.0.1 and Ubuntu 14.04.

I used `sudo -H pip install...` at some point. Could that be causing this?

Comment: Looks like you need to `pip install requests` before running awsebcli

Comment: `Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` is what it gives me.

Comment: Please post the output of `pip freeze`. You might have another package in the same environment requiring a different version of requests. Assuming you only need awscli to work, you can try and `pip install requests==2.9.1` for instance.

Comment: Tried the install with the version number and got weird output, plus no change in ebcli.

Comment: My real problem is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42723302/how-to-update-an-elastic-beanstalk-app-from-the-aws-command-line-tool, which I used to do with the ebcli. I'm happy to use the official aws command line tools, but they don't provide a way to update code.

Comment: You can upgrade requests using `pip install requests --upgrade` so you'll get a more recent version.

Comment: @spg, did that. It's now v2.13.0, which is outside the range, and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Okay, errors changed. Updating the question.

Comment: Ah, finally working. I upgraded termcolor, and some other things. I realize that pip is not something I know very well. The command I used to upgrade everything it said was missing was `sudo -H pip install requests --upgrade` then it needed me to upgrade termcolor too.